# setData() versus insertRows() Qt ModelView

Tags: c++, qt, model

In Qt model-view how is `setData` different than `insertRows`. I understand that `insertRows` is just for new rows addition, whereas `setData` can modify existing data as well. Can `setData` also be used to insert additional rows in a table or list based model. I am new to Qt, so please pardon if the question is too basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `setData()` is to be used to change existing data, or more precisely to manipulate data for an index that exists. You cannot add rows using this method.

Comment: And you also cannot set data by `insertRows`. They do different things.

Comment: @piwi : I was suspecting the same.Thanks a lot for clearing the doubt :)

Answer (score 0):

setData puts new data into your buffer, insertRows will add new rows into the indexed location of your buffer, increasing the total amount of data you now have. If you are trying to only overwrite data at certain locations I suggest using replace.